# Add constant current to an XL6019 module

Tags: led, voltage-regulator, current-source, constant-current

I need to add a circuit to an XL6019 module to get a constant current (adjustable) source to drive some SMD LEDs. I'm no expert in complex circuits and my level of knowledge in electronics is basic.

I've found a tutorial to add the same feature on a LM2587 module (https://www.instructables.com/id/Adding-a-Current-Limit-Feature-to-a-BuckBoost-Conv/) and used it as a reference for my project (I've actually just changed a resistor with a lower power rating one and the package of the voltage regulator).

The modules should have about the same specs and differ only by the main IC pinout. I can't understand if there is something wrong with my circuit or if I have to check the components for a failed one.

This is my schematic. The Wago connectors are used to connect the XL6019 output and the main 12V power source to the circuit. The JST-SH connector goes to a 3296w 10k trimmer with the same pin numbers as the port.

[image: PCB schematics]

Comment: As shown, what do you expect the circuit to do?

Comment: *i'm no expert in complex circuits and my level of knowledge in electronics is basic* Well, at least you earn points for challenging yourself. What makes you think that you can modify **any** circuit without the required expertise in circuit analysis and design skills? I bet that even for many fresh-from-University EEs making this modification will be a challenge. My suggestion: buy a ready made regulator module with current limitation option.

Comment: @Andyaka As i said the circuit and the XL6019 module should drive the LEDs with trimmable constant current.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Buying something already made was my idea from the beginning, unfortunately i didn't find any module with constant current, high enough voltage and small in size (i have limited space).

Comment: I don’t see the module.

Comment: The upper Wago connector is used to connect the circuit to the module (this is actually a schematic for the PCB), the out+ and out- ports are connected to the output of the XL6019 module.
The JST-RE called "feedback pin" goes to the feedback pin of the XL6019 main IC.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot drive 6 LEDs with 12V.

With 12V in and 6 LEDs you do not need boost buck, just boost.

You should use a $7 [Mean Well LDB-300L](https://eu.mouser.com/datasheet/2/260/LDB-L-SPEC-1291864.pdf) boost driver rather than the CV 12V source.  Its size is about 30 mm x 20mm

[image]

You would need to use LEDs that have a max current of 300 mA or higher.  They also have 350, 500, 600 mA models.

With a 12V input it can drive a string of LEDs with a Vf of up to 36V.

The LDB-300L has a PWM dimming pin that accepts frequencies between 100 and 1,000 hz.

[Mean Well LED Driver Catalog](http://www.meanwell.com/catalog/led/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have a variable voltage output with a trimmer on the XL6019 module .

Disconnect the LED's and trim the voltage to a higher value than the one needed for LED-s. If the white LED-s are 4V each (24V all) then trim the output to 30V.

The module has to always be in the current limiting range so the no load output voltage must be higher that LED highest voltage.

Use a power resistor instead of the LED-s to test your circuit.

Remove the resistor and put the LED-s back. It should work now.

If you have a fixed version  then there is not much you can do since the datasheet does not give information about it and the FB pin usage.